# Request for good research mailing list in Dynamical System & Chaos for notification of recent research results, conference, announcements

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

Are there some good research-level mathematics mailing list to be recommended in order to be notified of recent research results, news, announcements, conference, etc, particularly in Dynamical System & Chaos while other good ones are also desired ?

Comment: This isn't really on-topic for MO, which is intended for mathematical questions.  Occasionally questions about mathematical practice and the like are ok, but this question doesn't really fit.  I've voted to close.

Comment: Wait, hold on... which community? The MO community? There are *many* mailing lists for different sorts of communities.

Comment: @ToddTrimble It means the mailing list for recent research results, news, announcements, conference, etc. For me personally more focused on communities of PDE and Dynamical System. So it is desired to know whether there are some good mailing list to recommend.

Comment: "The" mailing list... maybe Google can help. I just tried this, and got some results. For PDE, maybe https://www.siam.org/activity/pde/, http://www.ma.hw.ac.uk/maxwell/PDEs/mail_list.php. For dynamical systems, maybe http://www.siam.org/activity/ds/, http://www.math.northwestern.edu/mwds/. If those are not suitable, then probably whoever is in charge at one of those lists can respond to a more focused inquiry from you. Sorry I can't be more helpful.